# iText LTV enabled - how to add more CRLs?

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to make a signed pdf LTV enabled. Signing certificate has a chain with three levels (root / public / personal). I know that it is necessary to add OCSP and CRL of certificates in pdf (except root).

- Can I use for it basic LtvVerification.addVerification() method?
  If I add in one run two CRLs, in the result PDF is only a second. If i change order, is there again a second.
  If I add the CRL in two runs, it will end the same way - in pdf remains CRL added as a second.
  I thought the "add" will not overwrite the previous state..
- How to properly use the method LtvVerification.merge()? Before/after adding first/second/both CRL?
- Or i can use only alternative method LtvVerification.addVerification(String signatureName, Collection ocsps, Collection crls,                           Collection certs)?

Thank you very much for the tips.

Source code:

```
public void addLtv(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException
{

    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(src);
    System.out.println("Source file: " + src);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(r, fos, '\0', true);
    LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();
    AcroFields fields = stp.getAcroFields();

    ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
    String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
    System.out.println("found signature: " + sigName);
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(sigName);

    //add LTV
    OcspClient ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
    CrlClient crlClient1 = new CrlClientOnline("http://www.postsignum.cz/crl/psrootqca2.crl");
    ArrayList<CrlClient> crllist = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
    crllist.add(crlClient1);
    CrlClient crlClient2 = new CrlClientOnline("http://www.postsignum.cz/crl/pspublicca2.crl");
    crllist.add(crlClient2);
    System.out.println("crllist.size=" + crllist.size());

    if (pkcs7.isTsp())
    {
        for (CrlClient crlclient : crllist)
        {
            if (v.addVerification(sigName, new OcspClientBouncyCastle(), crlclient,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateOption.SIGNING_CERTIFICATE,
                    LtvVerification.Level.CRL,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO)) {
                System.out.println("crl " + crlclient.toString() + " added to timestamp");
            }
        }

    } else{


        for (String name : names)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < crllist.size(); i++) {
                if (v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crllist.get(i),
                        LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                        LtvVerification.Level.CRL,
                        LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO)) {
                    System.out.println("crl " + crllist.get(i).toString() + " added to " + name);
                }

                if (i > 0) {
                    System.out.println("found verification, merge");
                    v.merge();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    stp.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample document to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sample source pdf (signed) http://www.quarim.cz/custom/itextLTV/source_signed.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide multiple CRLs to `LtvVerification.addVerification`, you do *not* call that method *once for each CRL* but *instead once with all CRLs*.

For this `CrlClientOnline` also accepts multiple URLs:

```
/**
 * Creates a CrlClientOnline instance using one or more URLs.
 */
public CrlClientOnline(String... crls)
```

Thus, by using this constructor instead we simplify and fix your code to

```
PdfReader r = new PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(r, fos, '\0', true);
LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();
AcroFields fields = stp.getAcroFields();

ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
System.out.println("found signature: " + sigName);
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(sigName);

//add LTV
OcspClient ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
CrlClient crlClient = new CrlClientOnline("http://www.postsignum.cz/crl/psrootqca2.crl", "http://www.postsignum.cz/crl/pspublicca2.crl");

if (pkcs7.isTsp())
{
    if (v.addVerification(sigName, new OcspClientBouncyCastle(), crlClient,
            LtvVerification.CertificateOption.SIGNING_CERTIFICATE,
            LtvVerification.Level.CRL,
            LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO))
    {
        System.out.println("crl " + crlClient.toString() + " added to timestamp");
    }
}
else
{
    for (String name : names)
    {
        if (v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crlClient,
                LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                LtvVerification.Level.CRL,
                LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO))
        {
            System.out.println("crl " + crlClient.toString() + " added to " + name);
        }
    }
}
stp.close();
```

*([AddLtvCrls.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/AddLtvCrls.java), method `addLtvFixed`)*

Applying it to your sample file, we get:

[image: Signature panel view]

---

For some background, `LtvVerification.addVerification` stores the information it has as **the** validation information required for the signature in question. Calling it multiple times results in the information only from the last attempt to count.

Calling `LtvVerification.merge` does not help either here as it merely merges validation information required for different signatures from older revisions into the new validation related information section.